# How to add ffmpeg watermark text on this PHP video upload?

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

Below is the code for my video upload

```
if (isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {


     if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] != "") {
         $id = $_GET['id'];
    }/* else {
        $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    }*/
   extract($_POST) ;

    $path = "video/answer_video/"; //set your folder path
    //set the valid file extensions 
   // $valid_formats = array("mp4", "jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp", "jpeg", "GIF", "JPG", "PNG", "doc", "txt", "docx", "pdf", "xls", "xlsx"); //add the formats you want to upload
 $valid_formats = array("mp4"); //add the formats you want to upload

    $name = $_FILES['answer_video']['name']; //get the name of the file

    $size = $_FILES['answer_video']['size']; //get the size of the file

    if (strlen($name)) { //check if the file is selected or cancelled after pressing the browse button.
        list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name); //extract the name and extension of the file
        if (in_array($ext, $valid_formats)) { //if the file is valid go on.
            if ($size ) { // check if the file size is more than 2 mb
                $file_name = $_POST['filename']; //get the file name
                $question_id = $_POST['question_id'];  
                // $title = $_POST['title']; 
                $title = strip_tags(trim($_POST['title']));
                //get hashtag from message
                $hashtag = gethashtags($title);

                //$tags = $_POST['tags']; 
                $category = $_POST['category']; 

                $tmp = $_FILES['answer_video']['tmp_name'];


                if (move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path . $name)) { //check if it the file move successfully.
                     $answer_video = $name;
                       $answer_type = "uploaded";

                    $video = $path . $name;
                    $length = 5;

$randomletter = substr(str_shuffle("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"), 0, $length);
                   $rand = rand(1,10000000);
$uniqueName = uniqid($rand);
$thumbnail = "images/thumbnail_{$uniqueName}_{$randomletter}.jpg";

// shell command [highly simplified, please don't run it plain on your script!]
shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $video -deinterlace -an -ss 1 -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -y -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg $thumbnail 2>&1");







                    $msg = "Uploaded Successfully!";   

                     echo json_encode(array('msg'=>$msg,'res'=>$question_id));
                      $userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

How do I add top right watermark . please do help

I tried many times but it didn't work..
Your help is appreciated..
Ffmpeg is working fine on the server and but didnt know how to do the above required .
I dont know how to implement the ffmpeg scripting on this.
I need to watermark before saving the video to folder.

Comment: Your title says 60 seconds but you later say 30 seconds. What didn't work, exactly? Are there any error messages? Did you get the ffmpeg command to work before attempting to script it, or do you need help with the scripting part?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I need to add a watermark image with the above upload script..please do help..

Comment: I already knew that is your ultimate goal, but I asked these questions to clarify where you need help exactly, but you ignored the questions.